# Why is a security context in .NET called a Principal?

Tags: .net, security

What is the etymology of .NET's [principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/principal-and-identity-objects)? Why did Microsoft choose this name to represent a security context?

Comment: A session has a security context for a security principal. Security principals are actors in the model, and they have been around since the NT 3.5 days. In Windows 2000 machines became a principal. That is, workstations and servers could be given permissions to access a securable object like a file or a semaphore on another machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called the same in Java, so it's not really a Microsoft-specific term. I don't know the exact etymology, but according to Wikipedia: "In commercial law, a principal is a person, legal or natural, who authorizes an agent to act to create one or more legal relationships with a third party."